Callout loop not allowed without additional callouts
I checked the existing posts on this however I have only one callout.
Error - {"statusCode":"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION","message":"Callout loop not allowed"
I am making a callout to createServiceReport endpoint.
Code is same as example -
String salesforceHost = System.Url.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm();
String url = salesforceHost + '/services/data/v41.0/actions/standard/createServiceReport';
// Create HTTP request
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint(url);
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
// Set the body as a JSON object
request.setBody('{"inputs" : [ {"entityId" : "0WOxx000000001E","signatures" : [{"data":"Base64 code for the captured signature image","contentType":"image/png","name":"Customer Signature","signatureType":"Default","place":"San Francisco","signedBy":"John Doe","signedDate":"2019-06-05 12:00:00"}],"templateId" : "0SLR00000004DBFOA2"} ]}');
Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
// Parse the JSON response
if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
    System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
                 response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
} else {
    System.debug(response.getBody());
}

however there is a trigger on Service Report object.

Disable trigger - Callout works
Enable trigger - Callout fails
Enable trigger but comment out everything  - Callout fails

So just keeping the trigger enabled without any code base also makes the callout fails
Has anyone any idea around the same

I have tried with future callout
Tried with Queueable callout without success


Have you looked at the debug log?

Yes the request just fails with the error.

Are you sure you successfully deployed the edited version of the trigger (the commenting out)?

I noticed you are using a pretty old API in your callout. Is your trigger using a newer API version? Maybe there is a conflict? Edit: looks like you can use v41.0 or greater.

When is your callout code being triggered?

It is a weird error that I could solve. The ServiceReport trigger had (before insert) as one of the parameters but no implementation for it.
